# 100% GPU Utilisation with MPC-HC using CUVID

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, video-playback

I'm using MPC-HC 1.7.8 that came from a K-Lite pack using the LAV (0.64) splitters and so on. On windows 7 64bit, with a Nvidia GTX 770. 
I want to use **madVR** and **CUVID** for the best playback, however having CUVID selected in MPC -> Internal Filters -> Video decoder causes my GPU to use its **maximum clock all the time** which uses a tremendous amount of electricity (and heat and so on). When **DXVA2** is used the load goes up and down during playback, it's more on 1080p videos that is, its using as much as it needs. Changing to EVR-CP makes no difference in either case.

How to configure all these tools so that I can use **CUVID** without causing it to take full control of the GPU constantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NVIDIA driver does this automatically when using CUVID, CUDA, or OpenCL.

With a tool called NVIDIA Inspector you can force the GPU in a desired powerstate for specific applications (such as MPC-HC).